# How can I spellcheck in gVim?

Tags: vim, spell-checking

What is the best way to spellcheck in gVim? Is there an add-on or something?
I would like it to offer corrections as well.

Comment: 99% of the time, Vim has the feature you want built in.  Add-ons are rarely necessary :)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use `:set spell` to turn on spell-checking.  If it's source code, gvim is smart enough to only spellcheck comments and string literals.

[`:help spell`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/spell.html) will give you all the details.  Here are some excerpts:

```
To search for the next misspelled word:

]s           Move to next misspelled word after the cursor.
             A count before the command can be used to repeat.
             'wrapscan' applies.

[s           Like "]s" but search backwards, find the misspelled
             word before the cursor.
```

```
Finding suggestions for bad words:

z=           For the word under/after the cursor, suggest correctly
             spelled words.
```

```
To add words to your own word list:

zg           Add word under the cursor as a good word
```

Also see [`:help set spelllang`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27spelllang%27) for information on changing your dictionary to include other regions, languages, or word sets (for example, medical jargon).

gvim must be compiled with |+syntax|.

I don't put `:set spell` in my .vimrc because when I'm coding there are just too many variable names in my comments that get flagged.  If there is a certain file type you want checked use an autocommand in your .vimrc.  Or just turn it on manually when you need it.

Comment: You forgot to mention how to turn on spellcheck, but those commands will be useful once it's on.  Use ":set spell" to turn it on.  note that if it's source code, it's smart enough to only spellcheck comments and string literals :)

Comment: On gvim, put the cursor on a misspelled word and right-click. A list of suggestions will be shown at the context menu.

Comment: Great, I'm amazed that when I set :set spelllang=ru, it offered to download missing spell files and after it worked! I love Vim

Comment: I put the following in my `.vimrc` to be able to toggle spell checking; `nnoremap <silent> <leader>s :set spell!<cr>`. (the `<leader>` key defaults to `\`)

Comment: "smart enough to only spellcheck comments and string literals". What about the cases when you use English in a variable name, and you want to make sure you've spelled it right...

Comment: Is it not possible to automatically move through all errors correcting them like `aspell -c`?

Comment: `:set spelloptions=camel` is also useful for spellchecking camelCase and PascalCase words

Comment: "If it's source code, gvim is smart enough to only spellcheck comments and string literals. ... I don't put `:set spell` in my .vimrc because when I'm coding there are just too many variable names in my comments that get flagged."

Isn't that a contradiction? If it's flagging variable names, then it's not checking only comments and string literals.

Answer (score 6):

```
:setlocal spell spelllang=en_us
:set spell
```

For spell checker and to activate right button on mouse:

```
:set mousemodel=popup
```

When you place the cursor on the word and click on right button, gvim purpose different correct words.

You can put it on your `~/.vimrc`

Answer (score 5):

Do `:set spell` to turn on spell-checking.  See `:h spell` for help and info about how spell-checking works and how to use different languages and dictionaries and such.

Answer (score 2):

I started using

> aspell

which comes with Cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/).  (It's a package, but the default install plus manually-added aspell is pretty tiny and quick to download.)

When I want to spell check the current file, I use a function defined in my .vimrc (or _vimrc) that saves the file, runs aspell on it, then reloads the file:

```
:function! SpellCheck()
:   w!
:   !c:\prog\cygwin\bin\aspell.exe --dont-backup check "%"
:   e! %
:endfunction
```

to use this function I just do:

```
:call SpellCheck()
```

It goes through the file just like Microsoft Word would, I exit, and then the file is reloaded with corrections.

Running aspell externally without having to move my mouse is integrated enough for me.  I've never liked on-the-fly spell checking.  I find it and things like IntelliSense distracting.

Comment: Clever, but Vim beat you to the punch. Then again, who's surprised?

Comment: @Kazark in Vim is not possible to automatically move through all errors correcting them like `aspell -c` does?

Comment: @cirosantilli `]s` jumps to the next error and `[s` jumps to the previous error.

Comment: @Kazark I knew about those commands, but then if you have a large file with many errors to correct you have to `]sz=` for each word which is a bit inconvenient.